# kubectl logs return "Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, docker-image

I have the problem with my local Kubernetes using kubectl logs, other kubectl syntax is working. I run the image in my local Kubernetes, and I want to check the error logs in my local Kubernetes pod using `kubectl logs -f podname-js554d5`, but it's the return

```
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install Dotnet SDK from:
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
```

maybe anyone here knows what is the problem?

thanks.

Comment: It returned you the pod logs. That very line is what pod has output.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "other kubectl syntax is working"?

Comment: thanks @zerkms, you're right. i think that return is because "kubectl logs" syntax is not working

Comment: "syntax is not working" --- it's working just fine, it returned you logs.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. I can spin the same image up on Docker but not Kubernetes. Did you find a resolution?